# Using the $ Alias Without Creating Global Conflicts

Tags: jquery

For learning jQuery i am going through the book "Jquery: CookBook". In this book i gone through the concept of using $ alias of 'jQuery' without creating Global Conflict. As per the book the syntax is as follows:

```
  <html>
  <head> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js">
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <script>
   (function($){         //function to create private scope with $ parameter
        alert("Hello");    //private scope and using $ without worry of conflict
    })(jQuery); 
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the above code is not working and firebug shows syntax error. I am not able to find any document based on above concept. can anyone please tell me that how to use the above syntax correctly.Thanks in advance. i know the above syntax looks weird. But the book says:

All jQuery code could be encapsulated inside the following self-invoking
function:

```
(function($){ //function to create private scope with $ parameter
//private scope and using $ without worry of conflict
})(jQuery); //invoke nameless function and pass it the jQuery object
```

Comment: is jquery included before this is run?

Comment: @MandarDeshpande Could you please post the error message?

Comment: Please post the error message from the console.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (     -- on first line

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes Jquery is included before worked.

Comment: Do you have any other code preceding the script tag?

Comment: No error found, can you post the full script?

Comment: Please add your full script to the question

Answer (score 0):

Well after some efforts i finally got the answer.There is one jquery API for this called jQuery.noConflict(). Following is the way to use it:

```
    <!doctype html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>No conflict</title>
                <script src="jquery.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body>
            <p>Click Here </p>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $.noConflict();
           jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.            

    $('p').click(function(){

                alert("Hello");
                });

      });


            </script>

            </body>
        </html>
```